# loop over different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have 59 different dataframes of different participants. Each participants has his/her own dataframe because that is necessary for splitting the right way in train and test groups later on.

Now I want to add a new column `AcuteLegs_3days`, which I knew works like this:

```py
trainingload['AcuteLegs_3days']=trainingload["AcuteLegs_1day"].rolling(3).sum()
trainingload['AcuteLegs_3days']=trainingload['AcuteLegs_3days'].shift(1)
```

But can I do this for all 59 dataframes at once?

I have a list of all dataframe names:

```py
participants = ['df_participant1', 'df_participant2', ...]
```

I tried to build a for loop but it is not working

```py
for df in participants:
    df['AcuteLegs_3days']=df["AcuteLegs_1day"].rolling(3).sum()
    df['AcuteLegs_3days']=df['AcuteLegs_3days'].shift(1)
```

this gives the error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: If they are really df names, then `for df_name in participants: df = locals()[df_name]; ...` (other rows are same as you had before). Although you're probably doing something wrong, if you have 59 independent dataframes of the same shape.

Comment: Thank you for this comment, its working perfectly right now. Can you collaborate on what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your participants list is a list of strings, not a list of actual dataframes.

You can either create a list of dataframes, removing quotes:

```
participants = [df_participant1, df_participant2, ...]
```

and continue as you do now or get dataframe from locals (as I proposed in comments):

```py
for df_name in participants: 
    df = locals()[df_name]
    df['AcuteLegs_3days']=df["AcuteLegs_1day"].rolling(3).sum()
    df['AcuteLegs_3days']=df['AcuteLegs_3days'].shift(1)
```

Currently you're trying to use strings as dataframes, which obviously fails (e.g. you have a list of names, not variables). So you try to execute the following:

```py
'df_participant1'['AcuteLegs_3Days']
```

and strings can be indexed only by integers (well, strictly speaking, anything with [`__index__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__) defined) or slices. You cannot say `'foo'['bar']`, because it simply makes no sense.